# Consulta generar varios hilos que simulen clientes en nodejs

Tags: nodejs

Tengo n nombres que simulan clientes lo que quiero hacer es iterar sobre cada uno de ellos y me envie n peticiones a un endpoint en nodejs

aqui tengo la parte del codigo correspondiente a lo que les digo

```
  sensors=["Rimac","Cercado"];

  for (sensor in sensors){
  var date = new Date().toJSON();

  var datos={
    name:sensors[sensor],
    valor:Math.random()*20,
    fecha:date
  };

console.log(datos);
    var options = {
  uri: 'http://localhost:7777/api/sensor',
  method: 'POST',
   headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        },
  json: datos
};

  request(options,function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
  }
});
  sleep(1000);


};
```

Los datos llegan al enpoint con normalidad pero,
si le pongo un for a la parte anterior para que quede así

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
  for (sensor in sensors){
  var date = new Date().toJSON();

  var datos={
    name:sensors[sensor],
    valor:Math.random()*20,
    fecha:date
  };

console.log(datos);
    var options = {
  uri: 'http://localhost:7777/api/sensor',
  method: 'POST',
   headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        },
  json: datos
};

  request(options,function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
  }
});
  sleep(10000);


};
}
```

Los datos no llegan al endpoint, a que se debe?,  me parece que es por un tema de asincronia.

***Edito1***

Buenas les agrego el cod que controla el tema del post en el servidor

```
module.exports=function(app,Sensor,io){
var express=require("express");
var router=require("express").Router(); 

  router.route("/sensor").get(function (req, res){
  Sensor.find(
    function(err, Sensor) {
      if (err)
        res.send(err)
      else{
        console.log("Exito al retornar todo");
        res.json(Sensor);

      }
      // devuelve todas las Sensors en JSON
        }
      );
}).post(function(req,res){
  console.log("BODY=");
  console.log(req.body)
    Sensor.create(
    {
    name:req.body.name,
     Valor:req.body.valor,
     Fecha:req.body.fecha
   } , function(err) {
        if (err){
          console.log("HUBO UN ERROR",err);
          res.send(err);
        }
        else{

        var temp = parseFloat(req.body.valor);
        var date = new Date(req.body.fecha); 
        console.log(date);
        console.log(temp);
        //Se pasan los datos a el cliente web ahi se manejara para mostrar la grafica en tiempo real mediante higcharts
        io.sockets.emit('post', date.getTime() - ( date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000) , temp ,req.body.name);    
        console.log("Dato creado exitosamente");
}

});
});

  return router;
}
```

Imagen del cliente cuando envia los datos ,SIN USAR EL FOR HASTA 100, es decir solo se envia una instancia

http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-screenshotfrom2016-9618315.html

Imagen del servidor al recibir esta instancia, hasta aqui todo bien sale lo que quiero, el problema es cuando quiero emular 100 200 o n peticiones.

http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-screenshotfrom2016-9618316.html

AQui cuando agrego el for hasta 100 , para tener 100 peticiones tanto de Rimac como Cercado.

Enviando datos
http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-screenshotfrom2016-9618325.html

Servidor NO recibe datos

http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-screenshotfrom2016-9618331.html

Tambien esta el tema de por ejemplo como es un for todo se envia de manera lineal , como añadiria sincronia a las peticiones? , pense en hilos , vengo de java ,si tienen ejemplos compartalo por favor.

***Edito3***

Como hice para 100 peticiones en 100 segundos no alcanzaba a llegar al final reduci a 10 y veo que las peticiones si se envian , pero se envian en bloque a que me refiero, a que tiene que terminar el for del client y recien ahi salen el servidor ,lo que quiero es que se envien constantemente no en bloque.

Además el callback del request en el client no se ejecuta, sino cuando cierro el servidor.

Comment: ¿estás usando request así: `var request = require('request');`?

Comment: si,asi lo estoy usando,por eso solo puse la parte del cod en la que esta el problema y como dije , cuando no pongo el bucle los datos si se envian,solo 2 , pero si pongo por ejem un bucle para100 peticiones , en el servidor sale que llegan , pero es como si la coneccion aun permaneciera , y no sale el resultado de sucess final,por consecuente el socket no se envia.

Comment: ¿y también `var sleep = require('sleep').sleep` ?

Comment: no , el sleep es una funcion que encontre , pues el sleep de npm creo que hace uso de python , y quiero la mas independencia posible,pero igual funciona.

Comment: Ese `sleep( )` tiene **muy mala pinta**. Hay un módulo `sleep` en **npm** que **bloquea todo el bucle de eventos de node**. Si eso es lo que estás usando, ese es tu problema. Si bloqueas el bucle de eventos, ni se envian ni se reciben datos. Investiga sobre `setTimeout( )` o `setInterval( )`, y quita ese `sleep( )`.

Answer (score 1):

La segunda función a mí me anda. Solo le falta definir `sensors`

```
for(i=0;i<100;i++){
  var sensors=["Rimac","Cercado"];
  for (var sensor in sensors){
```

Subí lo que probé a [github](https://github.com/codenautas/pruebas_de_concepto/tree/master/stackoverflow/16017)

(para mis pruebas supongo que están corriendo en procesos separados el frontend y el backend, si no fuera así el problema puede estar en el sleep que es sincrónico)

Comment: Editare el post poniendo mas información con imagenes , ya revise tu código , pero no me funciona.

Comment: Consejo: Poner como primer renglón `"use strict";` mejora el control (que estén todas las variables declaradas, lo cual ayuda a no cometer errores de tipeo y otros similares)